# Delete a dictionary item if the key exists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any other way to delete an item in a dictionary only if the given key exists, other than:

```
if key in mydict:
    del mydict[key]
```

The scenario is that I'm given a collection of keys to be removed from a given dictionary, but I am not certain if all of them exist in the dictionary. Just in case I miss a more efficient solution.

Comment: @user1929959 Nope, that question wants a copy of the dictionary, and doesn't care about hte case that the key is not in the input.

Answer (score 961, accepted):

You can use  [`dict.pop`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```
 mydict.pop("key", None)
```

Note that if the second argument, i.e. `None` is not given, `KeyError` is raised if the key is not in the dictionary. Providing the second argument prevents the conditional exception.

Comment: For reference, the second argument to `.pop()` is what it returns if the key is not found.

Comment: Does this only do 1 lookup?

Comment: So, just for curiosity, what is the default value of the second argument in the source code?

Comment: @CarlosPinzón There isn't one. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop).  `D.pop(key[, default])` "If `key` is not found, `default` is returned if given, otherwise `KeyError` is raised".

Comment: @GirishGupta: I doubt it.  Python `dict` is written in C.  I would be very surprised if not optimised for single lookup.  Ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L2206

Comment: **`.pop()` does a single lookup, as seen in the Python source code:** https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34e93d3998bab8acd651c50724eb1977f4860a08/Objects/dictobject.c#L2231

Answer (score 29):

There is also:

```
try:
    del mydict[key]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

This only does 1 lookup instead of 2.  However, `except` clauses are expensive, so if you end up hitting the except clause frequently, this will probably be less efficient than what you already have.

Comment: that is my fear. I wasn't sure about the cost of two look-ups per deletion vs. that of using try-except.

Comment: @SimonHughes -- See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663) on programmers ...

Comment: This is called the [eaiser to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (EAFP) Python style.

Comment: And EAFP is the recommended approach in Python.  I would like to see the evidence and rationale for the statement "except clauses are expensive."

Comment: @Bobort -- This has been a pretty well explained in a number of places.  See [this answer](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663) on programmers or [this response](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2011-January/081143.html) on the python mailing list.  In short, setting up the try/except block is cheap, but handling the exception is less cheap.

Answer (score 7):

## Approach: calculate keys to remove, mutate dict

Let's call `keys` the list/iterator of keys that you are given to remove. I'd do this:

```
keys_to_remove = set(keys).intersection(set(mydict.keys()))
for key in keys_to_remove:
    del mydict[key]
```

You calculate up front all the affected items and operate on them.

## Approach: calculate keys to keep, make new dict with those keys

I prefer to create a new dictionary over mutating an existing one, so I would probably also consider this:

```
keys_to_keep = set(mydict.keys()) - set(keys)
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if k in keys_to_keep}
```

or:

```
keys_to_keep = set(mydict.keys()) - set(keys)
new_dict = {k: mydict[k] for k in keys_to_keep}
```

Comment: first approach doesn't look thread-safe to me