# remove Key in dictionary python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Please pardon me if it looks to be a duplicate. I have used the methods as provided at [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411107/delete-a-dictionary-item-if-the-key-exists)

Python version I am using 2.7.3. I am passing a dictionary into a function and Want to remove keys if a condition is true.

When I check the length before and after passing dictionary are same.

My code is:

```
def checkDomain(**dictArgum):

    for key in dictArgum.keys():

         inn=0
         out=0
         hel=0
         pred=dictArgum[key]

         #iterate over the value i.e pred.. increase inn, out and hel values

         if inn!=3 or out!=3 or hel!=6:
                   dictArgum.pop(key, None)# this tried
                   del dictArgum[key] ###This also doesn't remove the keys 

print "The old length is ", len(predictDict) #it prints 86

checkDomain(**predictDict) #pass my dictionary

print "Now the length is ", len(predictDict) #this also prints 86
```

Also, I request you to help me understand how to reply to the replies. Every time I fail to reply properly. The line breaks or writing code doesn't work with me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"understand how to reply to the replies"*? If you have a question about SO itself, consider http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yeah, you can't write multi-line comments. Edit your question to add significant information, including code. But you can use backticks for `inline monospace snippets`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi, I cannot get proper indentation, line breaks in my replies. I can post the questions properly, but have tough time in replying to comments.! :(

Comment: @LevLevitsky is right - comments are not the correct place to put code.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - Code edited. Sorry.

Comment: I was not referring to the code in your question. I was answering your question about replying to answers. "Replies to replies" are called "comments on answers" in Stack Overflow terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the dictionary is unpacked and repacked into the keyword parameter `**dictArgum`, so the dictionary you see inside the function is **a different object**:

```
>>> def demo(**kwargs):
    print id(kwargs)


>>> d = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> id(d)
50940928
>>> demo(**d)
50939920 # different id, different object
```

Instead, pass the dictionary directly:

```
def checkDomain(dictArgum): # no asterisks here

    ...

print "The old length is ", len(predictDict)

checkDomain(predictDict) # or here
```

or `return` and assign it:

```
def checkDomain(**dictArgum):

    ...

    return dictArgum # return modified dict

print "The old length is ", len(predictDict)

predictDict = checkDomain(**predictDict) # assign to old name
```